# Unable to Schedule a python job in intervals with specific Start time

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

We have a requirement to schedule a python job in Flask in hourly basis, The below code snippet which is working as expected..

```
   from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
   scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
   scheduler.add_job(func=sched, trigger="interval", seconds=60*60)
   scheduler.start()
   atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

But facing a challenge that usually we will deploy our application anywhere between 2:00 PM - 4:00 PM PST. For an instance 2:15 PM is code deployed successfully. The above code started triggering from 3:15 PM with interval of 1 hour. But instead we want the python job to start trigger from 3:00 PM and Interval 1 hour to be followed.

In simpler terms: If Code deployed 2:15 PM --> Job Start_time should be 3:00 PM , 4:00 PM , 5:00 PM...So on.

So we Tried **next_run_time** but no luck: --> **The code didn't even triggered**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
start_at=datetime.now(timezone('America/Los_Angeles')).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, 
minute=0)+timedelta(minutes=60) #To convert 2:15 PM to 3:00 PM
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=sched_onefilm, trigger="interval", seconds=60*5,next_run_time=start_at)
scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Also tried **Start_date** :  --> **The code didn't even triggered**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
start_at=datetime.now(timezone('America/Los_Angeles')).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, 
minute=0)+timedelta(minutes=60)
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=sched_onefilm, trigger="interval", seconds=60*5,start_date=start_at)
scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 links that I think will answer your question.  You'll need to pour through the documentation to customize your particular solution.

All 3 are from Digital Ocean's documentation:

1. https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#configuring-the-scheduler
2. https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler
3. https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron

In the 3rd link they state: "For example, day=1, minute=20 is equivalent to year='*', month='*', day=1, week='*', day_of_week='*', hour='*', minute=20, second=0. The job will then execute on the first day of every month on every year at 20 minutes of every hour."

I want my cron job to run every day at 1am so I used:

```
scheduler.add_job(func=renew_subscription, trigger="cron", hour=1)
```

but for testing purposes I used so I could see the code run every minute at the 30 second mark:

```
scheduler.add_job(func=renew_subscription, trigger="cron", second=30)
```

Comment: The question is about "start time". I also struggling with this.